# In React, State value changes when navigating to another component or pressing the back button in browser

Tags: reactjs

I'm just new to react, I'm doing one simple project to learn react.
In that while navigating between components or pressing the back button in the browser, the state value changes to null. (i.e the value before initialisation).

 
**My question is how to preserve the state value while navigating between the components or when pressing the back button in the browser.**


Here my sample code:

P.S. Ignore the css.

1. **App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {movies:[]};

    //This method fetches the movie details
    searchMovie = (movieQuery) => {
        fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=111111&s=${movieQuery}`) //Removed the apikey
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            this.setState({movies:json.Search});
        })
        .catch((err)=> {console.log(err.message);})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Search searchMovie = {this.searchMovie}/> 
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="row" id='movies'>
                        {
                            this.state.movies.map((movie) => {
                                const {imdbID,Title,Poster} = movie;
                                return(
                                    <div key={imdbID} className='card card-body col-md-3 col-sm-4 m-3' id='movie-card' style={{cursor:'pointer'}}>
                                        <Link to = {{
                                            pathname:'/movie',
                                            state:{imdbID:imdbID}
                                        }}>
                                        <img src={Poster} className='img-fluid mx-auto poster-img' onError={(e)=>{e.target.onerror = null; e.target.src='https://cm3inc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/npa2.jpg'}}/>
                                        <p className='movie-title'>{Title}</p>
                                        </Link>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })
                        } 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

2. **Search.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";


class Search extends Component {
    state = { movieQuery: '' }; //this value changes when navigating between components

    searchQuery = (event) => {
        this.setState({ movieQuery: event.target.value });
    }

    handleKeyPress = (event) => {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
            this.props.searchMovie(this.state.movieQuery);
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="jumbotron">
                    <h1 style={{textShadow: '2px 2px 4px #000000'}}>Movie Master</h1>
                    <p className="lead" style={{marginBottom:'10px'}}>This is a handy site to search details for a movie or series based on IMDB Data.</p>
                    <input className="search-input mr-2"
                        placeholder="Search Movie/Series Here..."
                        onChange={this.searchQuery}
                        onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} 
                    />
                    <button className="btn btn-primary my-2" onClick={this.props.searchMovie}>Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Search;
```

3.**Movie.js**

```
class Movie extends Component {
    state = { movie: [] };
    componentDidMount() {
        const { imdbID } = this.props.location.state;
        fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=1111111&i=${imdbID}`)
            .then((response) => { return response.json(); })
            .then((json) => {
                this.setState({ movie: json });
                console.log(this.state.movie);
            })
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.movie.Ratings) return null;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='container'>
                    <div className='card my-5'>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className='col-md-4'>
                                <img src={this.state.movie.Poster} className='img-fluid movie-image' style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} onError={(e) => { e.target.onerror = null; e.target.src = 'https://cm3inc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/npa2.jpg' }} />
                            </div>
                            <div className='col-md-8'>
                                <h3 className='movie-heading'>{this.state.movie.Title}</h3>
                                <ul className="list-group movie-details">
                                    <li className="list-group-item">
                                        <strong>Genre : &nbsp;</strong> {this.state.movie.Genre}
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="list-group-item">
                                        <strong>Released : &nbsp;</strong> {this.state.movie.Released}
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="list-group-item">
                                        <strong>Director : &nbsp;</strong> {this.state.movie.Director}
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="list-group-item">
                                        <strong>Writer : &nbsp;</strong> {this.state.movie.Writer}
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="list-group-item">
                                        <strong>Actors : &nbsp;</strong> {this.state.movie.Actors}
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="list-group-item">
                                        <strong>Rated : &nbsp;</strong> {this.state.movie.Rated}
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="list-group-item">
                                        <strong>Runtime : &nbsp;</strong> {this.state.movie.Runtime}
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="list-group-item">
                                        <strong>Production : &nbsp;</strong> {this.state.movie.Production}
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="list-group-item">
                                        <strong>Awards : &nbsp;</strong> {this.state.movie.Awards}
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='row' style={{ marginTop: '0px' }}>
                            <div className='col-12'>
                                <div className="card plot-card">
                                    <div className="card-header">Plot</div>
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <p className="card-text">{this.state.movie.Plot}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='row' style={{ marginTop: '0px' }}>
                            <div className='col-md-4'>
                                <ul className='list-group'>
                                    <li className="list-group-item">
                                        <strong>IMDB Rating : &nbsp;</strong> {this.state.movie.imdbRating} /10
                                            </li>
                                    <li className="list-group-item">
                                        <strong>IMDB Votes : &nbsp;</strong> {this.state.movie.imdbVotes}
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="list-group-item">
                                        <strong>Box Office : &nbsp;</strong> {this.state.movie.BoxOffice}
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div className='col-md-8'>
                                <div className="card-deck text-center">
                                    {
                                        this.state.movie.Ratings.map((rating) => {
                                            return (
                                                <div className="card rating-card" key={this.state.movie.imdbID}>
                                                    <div className="card-header">{rating.Source}</div>
                                                    <div className="card-body">
                                                        <p className="card-text">{rating.Value}</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            )
                                        })
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Movie;
```

Answer (score 1):

State in react is ephemeral. And when a component unmounts it will reset their state so to speak for that component so that the next time it mounts it will use the initial state again. Consider using redux if you need state management across a whole app.

If you need greater persistence after like back button or page refresh consider using local or session storage

Comment: Thank you bro. can i do without using redux?

Comment: you can use a concept in React of "lifting state up" to the parent. so the state from the component isn't getting "reset" all the time. have you got a specific example I can try and help with?

Comment: Okay bro. i will try that and respond to you what the result was. Thank you for answer

Comment: no worries. please accept the answer if it was ok and ask another one if you have one :)

Comment: Sorry bro. i just tried the "lifting state up" concept by refactoring my code. its works like the same before.

Comment: you need to give me a specific example of what you want fixing? lifting state wont fix the back button but I don't know what you want to achieve by hitting the back button?

Comment: Okay bro. I will it explain it. Im displaying the movie title in the App.js main page by user searchquery (search.js) after clicking on that movie title link it will redirect to another component (movie.js) in that it will display all details of that movie like cast, director, etc.. while hitting the back button, it doesn't display searched results title but it displays nothing. because the state value changes to null (before initialisation).